# problema con asp.net y jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, botón

Buen dia, tengo un pequeño problema, espero me puedan ayudar:
Tengo un formulario en ASP.Net, donde se cargan los datos del usuario, estos campos están deshabilitados para que no se puedan editar, pero tengo un botón con el cual habilitarlos, el problema es que al darle click este no funciona..

Este es mi boton:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="empEdit" class="btn btn-primary" ClientIDMode="Static"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></span> Editar</asp:LinkButton>
```

este mi código jquery:

```
$('#empEdit').click(function () {
$('[id^=emp]').removeProp('disabled');
});
```

los id de los campos empiezan con "emp", puse los id estáticos en asp para que no cambien al momento de cargar la pagina en el explorador con `ClientIDMode="Static"` y aun así no funciona...

Comment: Prueba con $('[id^=emp]').prop('disabled', ''); claro en el entendido que lo demás que omites del código esta correcto.

Comment: Despues de cambiar removeprop a prop me manda este mensaje Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at __doPostBack (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.js:2), <anonymous>:9:37)
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: acabo de editar la respuesta que te he dado, espero sea lo que andas buscando, de ser cierto, marca como aceptada mediante check verde al costado de la respuesta, así ayudaremos a mantener la salud del sitio por % de preguntas resueltas :D

Answer (score 3):

Es porque los ID que genera ASPnet WebForms tienen una nomenclatura basada en secciones, si es que tienes un masterpage por ejemplo el ID será algo así:`ctlSeccionDelMaster$IDdelComponente`, para atinarle correctamente al ID que buscas, te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
$("#<%=empEdit.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $('[id^=emp]').removeProp('disabled');
});
```

**Actualización 10 abril 2017**

Acabo de reproducir algo similar al entorno que tienes y espero que sea lo que tienes en mente:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="activarBotones()">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function activarBotones() {
        $('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').prop("disabled", false);
        $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').prop("disabled", false);
    }

</script>
```

En la página `aspx` que andas trabajando:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
}
```

Comment: david, no te entiendo, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y agregar todos los detalles, el enlace es http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/60436/edit :D

Comment: El problema es que al momento de darle click al botón, no funciona el código javascript o jquery, es decir no habilita los inputs para poder escribir en ellos, intento quitarle la propiedad disabled, o en su defecto ponerla en false.

Comment: respuesta editada, espero sea lo que buscas hermano @davidarellano

Answer (score 0):

Este es un fragmento del formulario, un input en ejecución:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$empNombre" value="AUTO LINEAS AMERICA S.A DE C.V." id="empNombre" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Cliente Mostrador" disabled="disabled" pmbx_context="ACE58F01-58AE-42C0-8238-BDBDBFA24F8D">
```

agrege lo del id al codigo jquery:

```
$("#<%=empEdit.ClientID %>").click(function () {
    $('[id^=emp]').prop('disabled', '');
});
```

aunque el botón tiene `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="empEdit" class="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="return btn_disable" ClientIDMode="Static"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></span> Editar</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ese botón solo sirve para habilitar los inputs o textboxs, por que no haces ese botón con html le pones un id y le cargas la función que ya tienes

```
<button id="btnEnable" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
//y el tu script lo dejas como esta
$('#btnEnable').click(function () {
   $('[id^=emp]').removeProp('disabled');
});
```